# CSS Icon position

Tags: css, reactjs

So i've been trying to change the icon position with Padding and Margin but the problem is that the 3 buttons moves along with it! I am trying to position the icon properly next to Sign in ! If anyone can help it would be great ! Thanks!

Here's my JSX code:

```
class Navigation extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div className ='navBar'>
        <div className= 'menu-right'>
          <NavLink className="navBtn" to="/about">About</NavLink>
          <NavLink className="navBtn" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
          <NavLink className="navBtn" to="/3oss">
            <svg className='signInIcon' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
              <path d="M256 256c52.805 0 96-43.201 96-96s-43.195-96-96-96-96 43.201-96 96 43.195 96 96 96zm0 48c-63.598 0-192 32.402-192 96v48h384v-48c0-63.598-128.402-96-192-96z"/>
            </svg>
            Sign in
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="logo">
          <NavLink to = "/">Logo </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.menu-right {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navBar {
  background-color: #dfe6e9;
  height: 70px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

a.navBtn {
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#00b894;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color:white;
}

a.navBtn:hover {
  background-color:#fd79a8;
}

a.navBtn:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  float:left;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;

}
.signInIcon {
  height: 20px;
}
```

Here's the result:
[image]

When i Try to use padding or Margin it on `.signInIcon` it give me that:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to tweak icon position. If you just want to shift something a few pixels, I like to use `position: relative;` Something like this:

```
position: relative;
top: -3px;
left: 2px;
```

Adapt to your liking. This way, the "footprint" of the original element remains. The repositioned render only affects the appearance position of the element you're "moving", not it's actual position in the document flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.signInIcon {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}
```